# How to check errors for gunicorn using sock

Tags: django, gunicorn

I have a Django project running using gunicorn sock(not port).

I am using supervisor to run it. The problem is - supervisor is saying that the process is running. Logs doesnt show anything.

But site says "Bad gateway". Nginx generally shows bad gateway when the gunicorn is not running. But here, gunicorn is running without errors but nginx shows bad gateway.

If it uses port, I would have tested locally using "wget http://localhost:8000" but since we use sock here, how to test if its really running and why its not showing any error.

Comment: post your nginx configuration file.

Comment: check your process stdout with `supervisorctl tail -f <name of your process>`. See more information on the command with `supervisorctl help tail`